# Why was a question asked by a 11-years old person not deleted? (my flag was tagged helpful)

Tags: support, terms-of-service, age

I flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68532609/8620333) where the OP explicitly said he's **11-years old**. The flag was helpful (all my comments deleted) but the question and the account are still there. Why?

It's a clear violation of [the terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age) or did I miss something?

I expected the question and the account to be deleted immediately.

> [image]

Comment: Yea, that should be deleted outright, as it's simply illegal to store account information for a minor (without parental consent, afaik). If the kid were clever, he'd just shut up about their age as everyone else did at that age...

Comment: That said, _"please don't let my hopes with this community shatter."_ Makes me very suspicious that this is just a troll...

Comment: @Cerbrus another *valid* reason to delete this rapidly ;)

Comment: PS: I can close the question as duplicate but doing this means that I am giving him an answer so I simply flagged the question and I invited everyone to not interact with him

Comment: @yivi my custom flag was a trivial one --> *The OP explicitely said he's 11 years old so he's not allowed to be here*

Comment: Maybe investigation showed that it's actually an adult's sock puppet? ;)

Comment: @yivi I also added some comment linking to the terms of service (they are deleted now) so I think I was clear enough

Comment: In a site I used to moderate we used to simple wipe out accounts if there was reasonable doubt about their age. Them saying _"I am 11"_, _is_ reasonable doubt. _"But it was a joke"_ didn't stop us from covering our legal asses. Imo, that's how SE should take care of this.

Comment: Aren't this kind of things elevated for CMs to handle?

Comment: and now we have another person 14-years old replying to the question. He lives in the Europe so not allowed to be here too -.-

Comment: As per [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102250/241919), consider using "contact us" instead. Though, mods also cannot just delete the account, [they have to let CM know and delete instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355420/241919) (that's probably why the flag is "helpful" but no visible action).

Comment: ^ Or maybe the moderator who reviewed the flag has confirmed that the user is using an account set up by an adult and with supervision (which is allowed, AFAIK). If that's the case the moderator might not be allowed to disclose that info.

Comment: SO is not in violation if they don't know user's age. SO also could not be bothered to acquire parental consent - which is a legal option. Just let kids be - warn them that they should not disclose their age, but that is as far as you should go. As regular user you don't have any obligations to report them. Unless kid exhibits some behavior that may indicate they are not mature enough to be threated as adults. To be fair many adults aren't, too.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: No, you can't tell your users not to disclose their age if they're under age. And any lawyer could rip your defense apart if you don't take care of a user that literally says _"I'm 11"_.

Comment: @Cerbrus They are not my users. I am not saying that SO should tell users not to disclose their age. I am saying that regular users can do that in case they encounter minors. Instead of flagging their post for mod attention. Once they do that it is game over.

Comment: I am saying that as a parent of three kids (no longer minors) that would be seriously upset if someone would not let them participate just because of their age. And if my kids are upset, I am upset ;)

Comment: Getting upset about not getting to participate is called entitlement, @DalijaPrasnikar. I'm sure you realize that SE simply has rules they have to follow. And your suggestion that regular users should just cover up the tracks of underage users is how you get suspended.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"any lawyer could rip your defense apart if you don't take care of a user that literally says "I'm 11""* - I haven't hunted for case law to check, but I am sceptical of this interpretation of the law. COPPA requires removal of PI only when the website operator has "actual knowledge" that they hold PI from users aged under-13. As a matter of plain English interpretation of those words, the simple fact that a user has stated their age in a post doesn't seem to meet that standard, since website operators often do not (and cannot possibly) know about all content on their website.

Comment: @MarkAmery: The only situation where you'd _have to_ defend not removing an underage user, is if you got into a legal situation because a user _is_ under age. In that case, if the user literally stated they're 11, you're legally screwed. I'm not saying you're legally required to believe a user saying they're 11, I'm saying that if it turns out they're not lying, and you didn't do anything about it, you legally have no defense. Better safe than sorry, when there's reasonable proof the user is under-age, wipe it.

Comment: To clarify, _"and you didn't do anything about it"_ implies that the site was made aware of the user's age, as is the case here.

Comment: @Cerbrus As for *"Getting upset about not getting to participate is called entitlement, @DalijaPrasnikar."* - well, sure - but Dalija clearly holds the view, which I sympathise with, that children *should* be entitled to participate on online fora, and that rules banning them are unjust just as they would be if they banned people for their race or sex. You could just as well (and entirely accurately) characterise someone defying an apartheid law as displaying "entitlement" to equal treatment, but that entirely elides the crucial question of whether they're *actually justly entitled to it*.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"To clarify, "and you didn't do anything about it" implies that the site was made aware of the user's age, as is the case here."* - right, which is why Dalija is arguing you should *not make the site aware of it*. It puts them in a position where they're legally obligated to do something that is (in Dalija's view) unfair. You're not obligated to put them into that position in the first place, and if you don't, the kid can keep using the site. So why snitch and force the company's hand?

Comment: Those rules are still the rules, though. Getting upset doesn't help. Be clever.

Comment: "So why snitch". If a kid is ignorantly stating their age on the internet they have a lesson to learn. They shouldn't. That aside, calling it "snitching" comes across as very toxic...

Comment: @MarkAmery Problem is that law allows parents to give consent. But for SO that part is too "complicated", so their option is just to disallow kids to participate. This is the part which bothers me, and this is why I am holding stance that we, regular users, should leave kids alone.

Comment: Proper legal parental consent isn't "complicated", it's ___complicated___. You have to register PII about the parents including legal documents with the consent. You're free to be of the opinion that we _"should leave kids alone"_, but I think that's irresponsible. Teach them kids how the internet works, instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus "Teach them kids how the internet works" That is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: I doubt kids will realize how serious COPPA is if you just tell them to lie. Yours might, but that's a pretty small sample group.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CMs work on a rotation to handle issues like underage users. We're expected to get to them within a day or so for the most part. The flag was handled (as Nick indicated) as a note from the mods that they'd let the CMs know about the user profile. The moderators **do not delete user profiles** that are underage because the staff have a special route that deletes the entire account and the PII associated with it.

A moderator deleting an underage user profile is *insufficient* to be COPPA compliant as it does not actually remove the user's PII from our database - particularly since moderators can only remove a profile on a single site - they can't remove the underlying account that contains the information and any other sites that were joined while the user was on site.

As to why the question wasn't deleted - we don't delete content from underage users unless it would otherwise be deleted by a profile deletion (negative score at time of deletion) so, in this case, the question *was* deleted when I removed the account but, in general, if the content an underage user creates is good, it will remain because the posts are not inherently PII.

Please, do use custom mod flags for this when you see it - the CM who is on duty at the time will be pinged in chat when a mod escalates it to us, so it's much faster for us than having it go through the `/contact` page.

Comment: We've been having a bit of a comment discussion about whether or not we should make SE aware of an under-age user, or if we should just warn the user to remove anything that indicates their age. What do you think about that?

Comment: @Cerbrus As normal users we have no obligation what-so-ever and it's up to the individual, mods however are supposed to

Comment: @Cerbrus Once the user has indicated on the site that they are underage, we're legally required to remove their profile - even if they're just joking about it. While we'd likely do more investigation for older accounts - someone who'd been on the site and contributed significantly - but for accounts that only have one or two posts, we don't do too much to check in with them about it. We appreciate if y'all would let us know (through the mods) about it but we don't have any way of requiring it.

Comment: Thank you @Catija. That was more of an answer than I was hoping for.

Comment: @Makyen: See? What harm was there in me just asking?

Comment: @Cerbrus I mean - it wasn't an easy comment to write. I've spent the last 30 minutes crafting it. So, in a sense, Makyen's comments were correct - it's a very difficult question to answer.

Comment: But it turned out to be an awesome comment. I just feel that Makyen basically telling me not to ask questions is... Yikes.

Comment: If it's helpful, there's some additional information in our policy post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355419/what-are-our-policies-regarding-underage-users/355420#355420) on MSE.

Comment: @Cerbrus I reacted that way, because you were putting Catija in a position where she'd need to repeat what's already been said in various official posts, with the only other possibility being that she say something which was contrary to the already existing policy (which would, potentially, have negative consequences for her, both for her employment *and*, potentially, criminal). Your answer here appeared to demonstrate an understanding of the legal situation, so your inquiry appeared to be intentionally putting Catija into that, potentially, hazardous position for little or no benefit.

Comment: Assume good faith mate :D I had no ill intentions, apologies if it came across that way.

Answer (score 6):

Your flag was a notification to the moderators to do *something*, and per the [under age user policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355419/what-are-our-policies-regarding-underage-users):

> If you find a user claiming to be under 16 escalate it to us through the "Contact Community Team" button and select the "underage user" template - this will flag the on-duty CM for action so ***we*** can investigate and, if deemed necessary, delete that account and all personal data associated with it.
> <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

In other words, the flag was marked helpful and the mod will have escalated it to the CM team, there is nothing more that they as mods are required to do as it's the CM team's job to investigate and act.

---

If you explicitly wanted the post/account deleted you should have requested that in your flag, although given that is not their responsibility, I would expect a response to the flag along the lines of:

> we've escalated this to the CM team, it's not our responsibility to delete the post/account prior to an investigation taking place

rather than acting on it in the way you requested.

Comment: *If you explicitly wanted the post/account deleted you should have requested that in your flag.* --> I thought it was the logical action to be taken after the flag was marked as helpful

Comment: @TemaniAfif The logical action is to investigate further, and maybe escalate the issue. Also, sometimes mods mark a flag as helpful because they appreciate the effort, but do not necessarily think an immediate action is warranted. So maybe the account will be deleted later. Maybe it won't. You did your part, and the mod "thanked you" for it by marking the flag "helpful".

Answer (score 1):

IANAL, but let's see what COPPA has to say about accounts belonging to users under 13 years of age:

In the [FAQ](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions-0#A.%20General%20Questions), under section A-3:

> ##### What is Personal Information?
>
> - A screen or user name that functions as online contact information;
> - A persistent identifier that can be used to recognize a user over time and across different websites or online services;

Check! A SO profile qualifies as PI.

So, what if someone lies about their age? Section A-12 of the FAQ has us covered:

> ##### Will the COPPA Rule prevent children from lying about their age to register for general audience sites or online services whose terms of service prohibit their participation?
>
> No. COPPA covers operators of general audience websites or online services only where such operators have actual knowledge that a child under age 13 is the person providing personal information. The Rule does not require operators to ask the age of visitors. <...> If, however, the operator later determines that a particular user is a child under age 13, COPPA’s notice and parental consent requirements will be triggered. <...>

This means that you don't *have* to pro-actively confirm a user's age, but if you find out they're under-age, COPPA rules apply, which mean you can't store their PI.

Then what?

We flip to section B-4 op the FAQ:

> ##### What should I do if my website or app doesn't comply with the Rule?
>
> First, until you get your website or online service into compliance, you must stop collecting, disclosing, or using personal information from children under age 13. <...>

Basically, get rid of the PI data (the account) and you're good. There are some instructions in there to review how the situation came to be, but that's a broader subject than this case.

Note that "Get rid" means complete deletion from the database / log files etc.

Comment: This answer could be improved by directly answering the question. In other words, directly answering "Why a question asked by a 11-years old person was not deleted?". While this comes close to answering that, it doesn't actually do so. Specifically, it doesn't explicitly state that questions, answers, and comments are not inherently personally identifiable information (PII). As such, COPPA doesn't require those to be deleted. Such user contributed content, which isn't PII, is not normally deleted beyond what normally happens to posts when an account is deleted.

Comment: @Makyen: I can't answer _why_ it wasn't deleted, but Nick's answer is likely the case. No need to copy that over to mine :-)